# ToLower std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, string, vector, tolower

This is related to question :

[String array to C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410992/string-array-to-c-function)

Although everything is working fine now, the only thing I am not able to accomplish is to **tolower** the user input as I am getting an error :

#### Function

```
bool lookupTerm(const std::string& term, const std::vector<std::string>& possible_names) {

    transform(term.begin(), term.end(), term.begin(), ::tolower);
    for (const std::string &possible_name : possible_names)
    {
        if (possible_name.compare(term) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Parameters

```
const std::vector<std::string> possible_asterisk         = { "star" , 
                                                              "asterisk" , 
                                                              "tilde"};
string term = "SoMeWorD";
```

#### Error

```
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from jdoodle.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _UnaryOperation = int (*)(int) throw ()]':
jdoodle.cpp:40:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4306:12: error: assignment of read-only location '__result.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::operator*()'
  *__result = __unary_op(*__first);
```

I know that transform should be receiving a string. How can I momentarily cast the **std::vector** to simply **string** so I can get that word to lowercase?

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need to ever directly compare something to 0. 0 is falsy, so the `!` operator can be used.

Comment: The error occurs because you're trying to modify a `const` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `term` is `const` reference. Make a copy before converting it to lowercase:

```
bool lookupTerm(const std::string& term, const std::vector<std::string>& possible_names) {
    std::string lower(term);
    transform(lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(), ::tolower);
    for (const std::string &possible_name : possible_names)
    {
        if (possible_name.compare(lower) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could also achieve the same effect by removing `const`, and taking the parameter by value:

```
bool lookupTerm(std::string term, const std::vector<std::string>& possible_names) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::transform` needs to be able to change the contents of whatever the third argument dereferences to.

That does not work in your case since `term` is a `const` object.

You can create function local object to store the transformed string.

```
std::string lowercaseTerm(term);
transform(term.begin(), term.end(), lowercaseTerm.begin(), ::tolower);
```

and then use `lowercaseTerm` in the following line.

```
  if (possible_name.compare(lowercaseTerm) == 0)
```